# Using the new Package Reference syntax in F# scripts

Tags: .net-core, f#

According to this Microsoft blog post section, [Package references in F# scripts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5/#package-references-in-f-scripts)
, I should be able to use the following syntax in an `fsx` script:

```
#r "nuget: FSharp.Data"
```

Unfortunately, the compiler gives me the following error:

```
The package management feature requires language version 5.0 use /langversion:preview F# Compiler(3302)
```

I believe I have `dotnet.core 5.0` installed correctly:

```sh
dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.100
 Commit:    5044b93829

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Mac OS X
 OS Version:  11.0
 OS Platform: Darwin
 RID:         osx.11.0-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.100/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.0
  Commit:  cf258a14b7

.NET SDKs installed:
  5.0.100-rc.1.20452.10 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.100 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.17 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0-rc.1.20451.14 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-downloa
```

How can I get this working correctly? Currently, the `fsx` script inside a dotnet core solution if that makes any difference. I'm using vscode with the `ionide` plugin to write F#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionide doesn't yet support F#5.

Comment: Just an update - Ionide now fully supports this, so this should just work "out of the box"

Answer (score 1):

As Isaac Abraham pointed out in his answer, the `Ionide` vscode package, at the time of this post, doesn't support F# 5.0 quite yet. However, the Ionide package helpfully does give the user the ability to enable a preview of F# 5.0 language features.

I fixed this compiler error by opening up the User's `settings.json` file and adding the following lines:

```json
"FSharp.fsiExtraParameters": [
    "--langversion:preview"
]
```